# How to call a function in Pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

How would you call a function in Pseudocode?

Here is my Python code that I wish to turn into pseudocode.

```
answer = add(4,7)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pseudocode are used to show your idea/algorithm to others. They're designed to be read by human, so, as long as others can understand it, it'd be OK.

The format you used is OK, and pretty much used by everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As that other guy said it can really be anything as long as people understand it. But if you came across this as some computing aqa student like I was, you'll want to look here: http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-GCSE-COMPSCI-W-TRB-PSEU.PDF

Defining a function is FUNCTION and running a function justrequires the function name with parentheses, like normal